# Cant run rails app locally after adding SSL for production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, mongoid3

I have recently added SSL for an Heroku hosted web app but now I cant run the app locally, the browser just spins forever and then in the terminal I get this error -

```
$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.12 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2013-07-22 11:46:26] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-07-22 11:46:26] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-02-22) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
[2013-07-22 11:46:26] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=34732 port=3000
[2013-07-22 11:51:07] ERROR bad Request-Line `:\x00\x00\x00'.
```

I don't nessessarily need SSL for development so don't need to add the `thin` gem or `nugenix` but how can I get it to run locally again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ryan Bates had a nice little episode on the topic of [adding SSL](http://railscasts.com/episodes/357-adding-ssl?view=asciicast) which addresses the development environment. The configuration involves pow and nginx. I will be soon trying it out for myself but not this week.

Comment: This did help but I only needed to use the first part of the video, adding POW.

Comment: Good stuff - glad you found the missing piece

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! By adding pow as the server I can run the app normally :)

To add POW to your app run this command `curl get.pow.cx | sh` and then `cd ~/.pow` followed by `ln -s /path/to/myapp`.

POW is well documented on the website http://pow.cx/ and as mentioned by another user Ryan Bates has a great video on SSL which explains how to add POW to your app -http://railscasts.com/episodes/357-adding-ssl

Comment: Please consider updating your question with the solution, or add a bit more detail here. This is for the benefit of people who will find this question via search. They are more likely to upvote a well-described solution :)

Comment: Hopefully this is okay now... apologies but I am still getting the hang of this.